# Why android app size is increasing after publishing on market?

Tags: android, size, google-play, apk

I have published my app on android market recently. It is showing the app size as 5.4MB whereas actual  apk size is 2.8MB. Why it is showing 2MB extra? What should i do to restrict my app size? Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your app size is increased because you on your Copy Protection Option `ON` in publishing option. **Market needs extra space to store those security related information.**

> Helps prevent copying of this application from the device. Increases
>   the amount of memory on the phone required to install the application.