# Google Developer Console and Publishing

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have 4 signed release build apks of different architectures (35.MB on average is size) and had submitted for Alpha and Beta testing. While as a tester I downloaded the app from Google Play Store, but it was showing up 111 MB file while I was downloading it.

I thought it was how it worked for Alpha and Beta, but while I move the same release to production I faced the same issue. Now the app is on production but I am worried the users may not panic for 111 MB app which was earlier as 35.40 MB on average for all devices. Refer screens below.

Earlier I never posted the builds for Alpha and Beta testing, but this time there was a requirement for Upgrade activity. 
[This one shows up in one of the apk release details:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfmkV.png)

[Info for the the same build:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09wkh.png)

Answer (score 0):

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716212/why-android-app-size-is-increasing-after-publishing-on-market) could be the answer.

> If that is a paid application, you may implement the Google Play licensing service, else (if free), implement your own copy protection scheme.

You may check this [github](https://github.com/photo/mobile-android/issues/289) post for more related issue.

Hope this helps.